# html pre tag is not displaying multilines according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print 3 lines text from screen. I used pre tag for its format. It is displaying 3 separate lines but it is cutting data from the end. Please see below my code and screen shot.

This is how it is on my screen:
[image]
and this is is it dispalying in print out. 
[image]
You see it is cutting data at the end on line 2.

Below is my html code:

```
@model MaxPanda.Domain.ViewModel.PrintWorkOrderModel
@using System.Globalization
@using MaxPanda.Domain.ViewModel

<style>
    table.printTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
        font-size: 17px;
    }    
    table.printTable > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
        font-size: 15px;
        width: 300px;
    }    
    pre {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: "Open Sans,1Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    }    
</style>

<table class="printTable">
    <tr class="printHeader">        
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)</td>
        <td><pre>@Model.Notes</pre></td>
        @*<td>@Model.Notes</td>*@
    </tr>       
</table>
```

Could you please have a look and let me know if I am using pre tag correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is what the default presentation of a pre element is supposed to do.

Set [the `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre-wrap` if you want to allow word wrapping.